# How to wire together 3 power supplies for 3 different pd rails with the same reference 0v

Tags: voltage, circuit-design, power-electronics, low-power

How would I wire together 3 bench power supplies to get potential differences of +12, +24 and -6V, all with respect to the same 0V?
All 3 of the bench power supplies have positive, negative and ground terminals.

I've looked online and cannot find something similar, which I find surprising. If anyone could point me in the direction of any resources that can help me I would much appreciate it.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Are you asking how to have three separate supplies with those voltages? If so, then why not use a SP3T switch?

Comment: Are the power supplies isolated? I would *expect* so, but you have to be sure. Do you have make and model numbers for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If** they are isolated PSUs, then you can set each one to the required voltages and connect them together. The two positive ones have their "negative" outputs connected together to be the 0 V rail, and the supply for the negative voltage has its *positive* output connected to the 0 V rail:

[image]

If there will be high currents between, say, -6 V and +12 V then there may be other considerations: please add a comment if that is the case.

Also, and a bit out of the scope of what you're doing, power supplies have a maximum rating which limits how much voltage you can create by putting them in series - you could not put a thousand 30 V PSUs in series to create a 30 kV supply. [The name of that rating escapes me - perhaps someone would be so kind as to add a comment with its name.]